# Header frame_id

Tags: ros, frame-id

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning ros and I have a question regarding frame_id in the Header (like in PoseStamped). If I understand correctly frame_id means to which tf the position is relative to. So does that mean if I have a point which I get from kinect and I want to send the robot the goal with frame_id /camera_rgb_optical_frame and it will automaticly transform the point into the correct space? Or have I misunderstood?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34684/header-frame_id/) by [ZeroCool](https://answers.ros.org/users/2321/zerocool/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2012-05-23

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `frame_id` in a message specifies the point of reference for data contained in that message.

For example, if I want to specify a goal that is 10 meters directly in front of my robot, I would first declare the "origin" of the robot, which I will name the `/base_link` frame. The origin of this `/base_link` frame (0,0,0) is located at the center of mass of my robot. I would send a goal of (10,0,0) in the `/base_link` frame.

In your scenario in which you have a sensor, the tf tree becomes slightly more complex. Let's say that I have a Kinect that's mounted at the very front of my robot, directly in front of the center of mass. I now declare an "origin" for that sensor and name it the `/kinect` frame. Since the sensor is mounted 0.25 meters in front of the center of mass, the transform (tf) from `/base_link` to `/kinect` is (0.25,0,0), or the transform from `/kinect` to `/base_link` is (-0.25,0,0) (because `/base_link` is 0.25 BEHIND the sensor).

Now is when tf becomes useful. Your sensor data arrives in the frame_id of the sensor collecting it (i.e. your kinect points arrive in the `/kinect` frame in my example). If the Kinect receives a point of 10.0 meters directly ahead, and you want to navigate to that point, your goal is (10,0,0) in the `/kinect` frame. However, remember that since your sensor is 0.25 meters IN FRONT of the robot's center, this goal is actually (10.25,0,0) in the `/base_link` frame. The beauty of tf is that it can transform points from the `/kinect` frame to the `/base_link` frame for you.

The only catch is that you must tell tf to perform this transform (you can learn to do this in the [tf tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials)). If you're trying to specify a goal for `move_base` or some other ROS navigation software, chances are that this transform is done for you already (`move_base` definitely does this for you). This has to be determined on a case-by-case basis, since sometimes it is done for you, but sometimes it is not.

**TL;DR**: If you're trying to send a goal to `move_base` using the navigation stack, you don't need to change the frame of the point. If you collect the data in the `/camera_rgb_optical_frame`, then you can send a goal in the `camera_rgb_optical_frame` and the navigation stack will take care of the transform for you.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZeroCool](https://answers.ros.org/users/2321/zerocool/) on 2012-05-23**:
So if I understand correctly if I am using move_base in your example i would just pass frame_id=/kinect to setGoal? Thank you very much for you thorough answer. You've cleared a lot!

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-23**:
In my example, yes, you could specify it in the `/kinect` frame

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-05-24**:
@DimitriProsser your explaination is very comprehensive, however, it contains a bug. The goal is at (10.25,0,0) in the `/base_link` frame: `/base_link (+0.25,0,0) /kinect (+10,0,0) goal`. If you want to transform *data* from one frame to another frame, you have to take the inverse of their tf.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-25**:
Thank you @Stephan. Good catch

**Comment by [Xegara](https://answers.ros.org/users/14401/xegara/) on 2014-05-23**:
Question, if the frame_id is the frame reference of all points in the message, what is the bearing of the
info.origin.position.x, y, z and info.origin.orientation.x, y, z, w?? I assume that the origin is with respect to the frame_id.. Are they points projected to its parent frame??